# i want to create a registration form in luma page#magento2#php#html

Tags: magento2, php, database, css, html

i created a contact form and i want the data that is written in that form to show up in admin panel can you let me know the process for performing and any links or code would be helpful for my training in magento 2
  [image]

Comment: It's a native feature of magento

Comment: no, i meant to say that it should be present in the luma page i want to develop this page through coding.By creating a new module

Comment: @MohamedElMrabet i want to create aa registration form in the luma page so that i can learn to develop the front end of magento 2